# Three way class toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two radio buttons to toggle two alternative texts and it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .displayNone { display: none; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="radio" name="toggle" />A
    <input type="radio" name="toggle" />B

    <span class="A">A</span>
    <span class="B displayNone">B</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[name=toggle]').change(function() {
        $('.A, .B').toggleClass('displayNone');
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to make it three radio buttons to toggle between three texts:

```
<input type="radio" name="toggle" />A
<input type="radio" name="toggle" />B
<input type="radio" name="toggle" />C

<span class="A">A</span>
<span class="B displayNone">B</span>
<span class="C displayNone">C</span>
```

The solution I'm thinking about looks too verbose. What would be the clean one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One further approach:

```
$('input:radio[name="toggle"]').change(
    function(){
        $('span')
            .eq($(this).index())
            .removeClass('displayNone')
            .siblings('span')
            .addClass('displayNone');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zMBKh/4/).

---

**Edited** to add, for the more up-to-date browsers, a pure CSS means of accomplishing the same:

```
input[type=radio]:nth-child(1):checked ~ span:nth-of-type(1),
input[type=radio]:nth-child(2):checked ~ span:nth-of-type(2),
input[type=radio]:nth-child(3):checked ~ span:nth-of-type(3){
    height: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f90;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zMBKh/6/).

jQuery References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`:radio` selector](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

CSS References:

- [CSS transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/).
- [`E ~ F` general-sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).
- [`:nth-child()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).
- [`:nth-child()` W3.org wiki entry](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anth-child).
- [`:nth-of-type()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo).
- [`:nth-of-type()` W3.org wiki entry](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anth-of-type).

Answer (score 3):

Here's one method: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8zXVm/2/)**.

```
$('input[name=toggle]').change(function() {
    $('span').addClass('displayNone').filter('span:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').removeClass('displayNone');
})​
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, this may not suit your needs exactly. Here's a pure CSS solution.

```
span {
  display: none;
}

​input[type="radio"]:checked + * + * + * {
  display: inline;
}​​
```

​

Comment: That's ridiculously inventive! +1 =)

Answer (score 1):

And here's another way to do it (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bauKH/)

```
<input type="radio" name="toggle" value="A" checked="true"/>A
<input type="radio" name="toggle" value="B"/>B
<input type="radio" name="toggle" value="C"/>C

<br />
<span id="A" class="data">A</span>
<span id="B" class="data displayNone">B</span>
<span id="C" class="data displayNone">C</span>
```

---

```
$('input[name=toggle]').change(function() {
    var newval = this.value;
    $(".data").each(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('displayNone', this.id != newval);
    });                                                    
});
```

The takeaway message here would be that you can use the optional second argument in [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to specify whether the class should be added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

Give all your text spans the same class, but different IDs:

```
<span class="foo" id="span_a">A</span>
<span class="foo displayNone" id="span_b">B</span>
<span class="foo displayNone" id="span_c">C</span>
```

Then hide them all before displaying the one you want

```
function show(x) {
    $(".foo").hide();
    $("#" + x).show();
}
```

Edit:

Or, you can use jQuery's **not** selector if you are seeing a flicker:

```
$(".foo").not("#" + x).hide();
$("#" + x).show();
```